# PyQGIS - Style Features individually based on attribute value - custom renderer as option?

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to colorize all features in all layers in my QGIS 2.8.2-Document based on a color-value, that is being determined for every Feature individually.
I do have a QtGui.QColor instance for every feature, but I still need to apply it to the Feature via a Renderer.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
layers = canvas.layers()

for layer in layers:
    iter = layer.getFeatures()
    for feature in iter:
        if  feature['ELEM_NR'] != '' and feature['ELEM_NR'] != NULL:
            # 
            color = QtGui.QColor()

            # ...
            # hexValue is being determined based on feature['ELEM_NR']
            # ...

            color = QtGui.QColor(hexValue )

            # how can I apply color to feature`?
```

Background (why I do not simply use graduated symbols):

Every Layer has an attribute that is kind of an id.
I want that every Feature (no matter which layer it is in), that has the same attribute-value, is colored the same way.

Because the the number of features differs between layers and the value range of the attribute is quit big, neither the catgorized nor the graduatedSymbol-Renderer [descibed here](http://snorf.net/blog/2014/03/04/symbology-of-vector-layers-in-qgis-python-plugins/) would bring the desired result (at least in my understanding).

Using a custom renderer as described in [the documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/de/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#appearance-symbology-of-vector-layers) looks promising, but I can't figure how to include this.

Any Idea?

Comment: You have the color value on the feature as a field?

Comment: Not yet, but I could easily generate such a field. How would that help?

Comment: I'm really confused on what you are trying to do. It seems you have a hex value that you are generating based on a field?  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Background is this: I have a road-network with complex IDs (something like 21548266_21548267_01). The features (street objects) in several thematic layers have the same attribute and are matched to single roads by sharing the same ID. My task is to prove that allocation done by others, which is not possible with a script, only by visual inspection. Because labels are not quite handy, I would like to use colorization.

Comment: So you just want to have the same colors over the different layers?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. Because the range and number of features differ from layer to layer, I can not use the common renderers. From my understanding, that would colorize features with the same value differently.

Comment: See my answer. That will help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a field (or you can use an expression for more complex things) you can bind the color to the field and use that value

[image]

Color field in this case just has a hex value `#FF33FF`

Comment: Okay, that worked for me so far, thanks. But it still would be handy set the attribute field as color-string programmatically. I would like to avoid doing this for every layer eacht time. Any Ideas anyone?